# Get only the highest value returned by Group By

Tags: php, mysql

Here's how my table (simplified) look like

```
agentID|amount
   1   |   5  
   2   |   2  
   3   |   4  
   3   |   2  
   1   |   3
```

Now if I do

```
SELECT agentID, SUM(amount) AS totalAmount FROM myTable GROUP BY agentID
```

I'd get the sum of amount for each agentID. But what if I'm only interested in the returned agentID that has the biggest sum(amount)?

Tried something like

```
SELECT agentID, MAX(SUM(amount) AS Bought) FROM myTable GROUP BY agentID
```

OR

```
SELECT MAX(SELECT agentID, SUM(amount) AS Bought FROM myTable GROUP BY agentID) FROM myTable
```

but it returns syntax error :p

Comment: Order by something desc limit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU CAN ADD **ORDER BY**  AT THE END

```
SELECT agentID, SUM(amount) AS totalAmount FROM myTable GROUP BY agentID ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: ouch never thought it's this straight forward.. thanks!